# JButton: Simulate JButton press without the action firing

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

My use case is I have some JButtons that fire actions to an ActionListener. I also use keystrokes to fire some of the same action commands to the AcionListener. When the keystroke shortcut fires an action that is also done by one of the buttons I want the button to look as though it was pressed but not to fire the event.

So I have looked into the AbstractButton API and I tried some of the methods there like setSelected but it didn't have the desired effect. Finally I have looked at the method doCLick to see if I could use remove the action firing part but this also doesn't work

```
 367       public void doClick(int pressTime) {
 368           Dimension size = getSize();
 369           model.setArmed(true);
 370           model.setPressed(true);
 371           paintImmediately(new Rectangle(0,0, size.width, size.height));
 372           try {
 373               Thread.currentThread().sleep(pressTime);
 374           } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
 375           }
 376           model.setPressed(false);
 377           model.setArmed(false);
 378       }
```

I had thought of removing all the listeners. Running the doClick and then adding them again but I thought something more elegant should be available.

A SSCE would be

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    JButton jb = new JButton("Test Button");
    jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("I don't want this to fire");
        }
    });
    jf.getContentPane().add(jb);
    jf.pack();
    jf.setVisible(true);

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    clickWithoutFiringAction(jb);
}

public static void clickWithoutFiringAction(JButton button){
    Dimension size = button.getSize();
    ButtonModel model = button.getModel();
            //I tried changing these combinations but I could not get the desired effect
    model.setArmed(true);
    model.setPressed(true);
    button.paintImmediately(new Rectangle(0,0, size.width, size.height));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(68);
    } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
    }
    model.setPressed(false);
    model.setArmed(false);
 }
}
```

Comment: Then what kind of event you want at click on button?

Comment: I don't want any event. Just the gui to look like it was pressed.

Comment: Remove jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {});

Comment: Removing the actionListener isn't an option. Although as I said I had that of removing them all using the `doClick` and adding them again after that. I feel there must be a better way of doing it.

Comment: means you want like it just seems like it pressed but hitting keybord's key pressed?

Comment: you will need to use a custom `DefaultButtonModel`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JButton` uses `DefaultButtonModel` which has `setPressed(boolean)` function for generating action performed event using `fireActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` function. You will need to extend this model and provide custom implementation for `setPressed(boolean b)` function for avoiding action event firing. Please refer to the source code of this model class for more details.

```
class CustomModel extends DefaultButtonModel
{


    @Override
    public void setPressed(boolean b){
        if((isPressed() == b) || !isEnabled()) {
            return;
        }

        if (b) {
            stateMask |= PRESSED;
        } else {
            stateMask &= ~PRESSED;
        }

        fireStateChanged();
    }

}
```

now, you can set the model: `jButton.setModel(new CustomModel());`

Answer (score 1):

When you want an action listener to be used by left clicking on a JButton, and you want to perform the action without left clicking on a JBUtton, you write a separate public method that performs the action.

Like you did with the clickWithoutFiringAction method.

So now, all your action listener has to do is perform the separate public method.

```
        final JButton jb = new JButton("Test Button");
        jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                clickWithoutFiringAction(jb);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Heh I didn't read carefully, like `Sage` wrote you must provide custom implementation of `setPressed()`.

<strike>Your example works just fine. You don't see the effect because delay between `model.setPressed(true);` and `model.setPressed(false);` is to short, just 68 milisecounds. Increase value in `Thread.sleep();` to couple seconds and you will see the effect.</strike>

```
 model.setArmed(true);
 model.setPressed(true);
 button.paintImmediately(new Rectangle(0,0, size.width, size.height));
 try {
    Thread.sleep(68); // to short delay.
 } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
 }
 model.setPressed(false);
 model.setArmed(false);
```