# How to make read-only JCheckBox in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, checkbox

I want to have column of check-boxes indicate the steps of long lasting procedure.

In this case check-boxes should not be changeable by users. They are changed by background process.

Unfortunately, if I call `setEnable(false)` I make check-box not only read-only, but also dimmed.

How to accomplish?

Comment: Not sure it's a good idea to use something that looks like an enabled checkbox but can't be clicked.  If you're after something that just indicates a step has been completed, why not just use an appropriate image?  Big green tick or something.

Comment: if you are using java7 you can use `JLayer` and consumes all events in the component

Comment: possible duplicate of [JButton: Simulate JButton press without the action firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440676/jbutton-simulate-jbutton-press-without-the-action-firing)

Answer (score 5):

Remove the MouseListener and Key Bindings from the check box.

```
MouseListener[] ml = (MouseListener[])checkBox.getListeners(MouseListener.class);

for (int i = 0; i < ml.length; i++)
    checkBox.removeMouseListener( ml[i] );

InputMap im = checkBox.getInputMap();
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "none");
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released SPACE"), "none");
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution here. Easy to implement and very straightforward. Whether or not having an immutable checkbox is a good idea is another story, but as far as implementation goes, this works great!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `JLayer` class if you are using Java7 or swingX(JXLayer).

Quick example:

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayer;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.plaf.LayerUI;

public class JCheckBoxUnselectable {


    public static void main(String args []){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Test checkbox");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("Test checkbox"));
        JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox();
        LayerUI<JComponent> layerUI = new MyLayerUISubclass();
        JLayer<JComponent> jlayer = new JLayer<>(checkbox, layerUI);

        panel.add (jlayer);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }



    static class MyLayerUISubclass extends LayerUI<JComponent>{


        @Override
        public void installUI(JComponent c) {
            super.installUI(c);
            JLayer jlayer = (JLayer)c;
            jlayer.setLayerEventMask(
                    AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK |
                    AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK 
                    );

        }

        @Override
        public void uninstallUI(JComponent c) {
            JLayer jlayer = (JLayer)c;
            jlayer.setLayerEventMask(0);
            super.uninstallUI(c);
        }


        @Override
        protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e, JLayer l) {
            e.consume();
        }





        @Override
        protected void processKeyEvent(KeyEvent e,
                JLayer<? extends JComponent> l) {
            e.consume();
        }



    }
}
```

Read more : [How to decorate components with JLayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html)

Comment: +1, Interesting approach, but it seems to mess up focus traversal, which may or may not be an issue depending on whether the check box should be focusable to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

This seems a little weird, but is going to present issues with how you would update the state, but, basically, you want to replace the `ButtonModel` with one whoes `selected` state can't be changed.

For example...

```
checkBox = new JCheckBox();
checkBox.setModel(new DefaultButtonModel() {

    @Override
    public boolean isSelected() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelected(boolean b) {
        // Stop events from being raised...
    }

});
```

Now, you may also want to make the check box unfocusable to prevent it from receiving keyboard focus.

Having said all that, as a user, I would find this incredibly frustrating as the check box "appears" editable

Comment: I have marked it as duplicate to eat out your reputation mua ha ha! :) ;)

Comment: @Sage Remember, I know where you post ;)

Comment: I dont like this kind of solution cause breaks liskov substitution principle

Comment: @nachokk I don't like the basic idea (of a read only checkbox)