# How to keep JCheckBox L&F as in enabled(true) when disabled?

Tags: java, swing, checkbox

I have a java application which has JCheckBoxes used to show the state of an object.
These CheckBoxes cannot/shouldnt be changed by the user.

So, obviously, I did:

```
checkbox.setEnabled(false);
```

However, now the Tick/icon image is grayed out.

I want the disabled JCheckBox to look BETTER, like its enabled but dont allow the user to change its state.

How can I do that?  How can I make the TICK image on the disabled CheckBox looks better (higher contrast) ?

[image: Example for Ilustration, notice how the UI is different for each checkbox]

Comment: Okay, because that's not going to be annoying to a user ... you need a "read only" `ButtonModel`

Comment: Is there anything like that on swingX or something?

Comment: I wouldn't think so - it's a counter intuitive request

Comment: Sorry, but the topic you mention doesnt really have a proper answer. It just makes the CheckBox read-only.. When I really just want to make the checkBox image different.

Comment: Ah-ha, but you don't want the user to change the state either, so you have a readonly check box, which can only show the state, but can't be change and which doesn't looked disabled ... let me know when that doesn't meet your requirements

Comment: I want to actually change the tick image/color on the CheckBox. Which isnt answered on that topic. Gonna have to ask somewhere else then.. Thanks.

Comment: With respect, before you ask somewhere else, you might want to clarify your request, because as I read it, you want a "readonly" checkbox, one which looks "enabled" but which doesn't allow the user to change it's state.  Another thing to do is to look at the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JCheckBox.html), which, although somewhat unclear, allow you to specify the `icon` for the control, which will check the check/unchecked icon displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the disabled JCheckBox to look BETTER, like its enabled but dont allow the user to change its state.

This says "readonly" `JCheckBox` to me.  In this case, you'd need to supply a `ButtonModel` which stops the state from been changed. For example [How to make read-only JCheckBox in Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556381/how-to-make-read-only-jcheckbox-in-swing/20556503#20556503)

> I want to actually change the tick image/color on the CheckBox

Then you need to use the [`JCheckBox#setSelectedIcon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setSelectedIcon-javax.swing.Icon-) and [`JCheckBox#setIcon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setIcon-javax.swing.Icon-) as well as the [`JCheckBox#setDisabledIcon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#getDisabledIcon--) and [`JCheckBox#getDisabledSelectedIcon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#getDisabledSelectedIcon--) methods to supply your own icons